# How to start with reactjs and webapi

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to **ReactJs**.

I want to start reactjs application with web api.
I have referred some samples but they are having reactjs as web application in separate project and web api as the separate project.

Here I have confused.

1. Do I need to run the application separately?
2. When I need to deploy the version, do i need to deploy it separately in the IIS?

Answer (score 1):

If it turned out that your examples do have the WebAPI and React placed in separate projects, then the answers to your questions are as follows:

1. Yes. Simply running the application won't start the WebAPI server. Assuming that you're using Visual Studio, there is a possibility to set multiple startup projects - using this will make sure that both the app and the API server are up and running.
2. I am not sure what do you mean by "separately". As you have effectively two applications, you do need to place them in a separate place on IIS.

Please note however, that you might not need that two-projects approach and you will be fine in keeping all of the things in one project - especially if you're still learning all the stuff. If that is the case, I recommend you to check out some extra templates/tutorials for reactJS, such as:
* [ReactJS.Net library](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html) - useful for small projects
* [ReactJS templates for .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) - especially if you want to explore .NET Core as well.